# DrawImage delete - PySimpleGUI

Tags: drawimage, pysimplegui

Need help with deleting only one DrawImage on my canvas in PySimpleGUI.
Canvas is loaded with a background image (100% of the canvas), and has 5 other DrawImage items on it (various sizes). When I click on one of those 5 images, I want THAT to be gone (deleted), but the background image to stay.

Using get_figures_at_location with coordinates derived from mouse click to delete the one image I want to go away. But my routine also deletes the background.

Any ideas? Could not find a way to do it after searching numerous forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the id returned when you draw background image by using `draw_image`, delete it after you confirmed it is not the background image by the id.

```py
draw = window['-GRAPH-']
bg_id = draw.draw_image(filename=filename)

...

figures = draw.get_figures_at_location((x, y))
if figures and figures[0] != bg_id:
    draw.delete_figure(figures[-1])    # index -1 for last one or top one
```

Following code show to delete all figures after mouse clicked on the figures. (Remember to replace it with your background image)

```py
from io import BytesIO
from random import randint
from PIL import Image
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def image_to_data(im):
    """
    Image object to bytes object.
    : Parameters
      im - Image object
    : Return
      bytes object.
    """
    with BytesIO() as output:
        im.save(output, format="PNG")
        data = output.getvalue()
    return data

width, height = size = (640, 480)

im = Image.open("D:/desktop.png")
new_im = im.resize(size)

font = ("Courier New", 11)
sg.theme("DarkBlue3")
sg.set_options(font=font)

layout = [
    [sg.Button('Redraw')],
    [sg.Graph(size, (0, 0), size, enable_events=True, key='-GRAPH-')],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)
draw = window['-GRAPH-']

background = draw.draw_image(data=image_to_data(new_im), location=(0, height))
ids = [draw.draw_image(data=emoji, location=(randint(0, width), randint(0, height)))
    for emoji in sg.EMOJI_BASE64_HAPPY_LIST]
print(ids)
while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break
    elif event == '-GRAPH-':
        location = values[event]
        figures = draw.get_figures_at_location(location)
        for figure in figures:
            if figure != background:
                draw.delete_figure(figure)
                ids.remove(figure)
    elif event == 'Redraw':
        for figure in ids:
            draw.delete_figure(figure)
        ids = [draw.draw_image(data=emoji, location=(randint(0, width), randint(0, height)))
            for emoji in sg.EMOJI_BASE64_HAPPY_LIST]

window.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect @jason-yang. Was able to take snippets from your code and use it to my solution :-)